# Couchdb installation not working on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, couchdb

I am trying couchdb on my Mac Osx machine as per the following guide link.

http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/mac.html

I received the following errors onscreen.

```
192-168-182-129:~ andywong$ brew install couchdb
Warning: You seem to have osx-gcc-installer installed.
Homebrew doesn't support osx-gcc-installer. It causes many builds to fail and
is an unlicensed distribution of really old Xcode files.
Please install the CLT or Xcode 5.1.1.
==> Downloading https://downloads.sf.net/project/machomebrew/Bottles/couchdb-1.6
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/couchdb-1.6.1_1.mountain_lion.bottle.tar.gz
==> Pouring couchdb-1.6.1_1.mountain_lion.bottle.tar.gz
==> Caveats
To test CouchDB run:
    curl http://127.0.0.1:5984/

The reply should look like:
    {"couchdb":"Welcome","uuid":"....","version":"1.6.1","vendor":{"version":"1.6.1-    1","name":"Homebrew"}}

To have launchd start couchdb at login:
    ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/couchdb/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents
Then to load couchdb now:
    launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.couchdb.plist
Or, if you don't want/need launchctl, you can just run:
    couchdb
/usr/bin/install_name_tool: object:     /usr/local/Cellar/couchdb/1.6.1_1/lib/couchdb/erlang/lib/couch-    1.6.1/priv/lib/couch_icu_driver.so malformed object (unknown load command 8)
Error: Failed to fix install names
The formula built, but you may encounter issues using it or linking other
formula against it.
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/couchdb/1.6.1_1: 636 files, 16M
192-168-182-129:~ andywong$ couchdb
/usr/local/bin/couchdb: line 301: /Users/andywong/@@HOMEBREW_PREFIX@@/opt/erlang/bin/erl:     No such file or directory
```

The error is pointing to this line

```
/usr/local/Cellar/couchdb/1.6.1_1/lib/couchdb/erlang/lib/couch-1.6.1/priv/lib/couch_icu_driver.so malformed object (unknown load command 8)
```

Has anyone seen this type of error before?  Is it something to do being not compatible with my spidermonkey library version?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't it make a sense to make a report for [homebrew](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues) instead?

Comment: Nope.  I haven't tried posting it on homebrew's github homepages.  I thought it's best to try Stackoverflow first in case someone may have encountered before first.  

Anyway, I just posted the question here.

https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/34724

Thanks!

Comment: In the meantime use the native OS X application. I'm having another issue with MacPorts (ErLang related) that I have already reported.